# Serial communication write

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have written a simple c# app having functionality of serial 
communication. I am using it to read and write to a device. The device 
recognizes *string commands*. I am successfuly able to read from device 
using this app. But peoblem is in writing(sending) commands to device.
I am simply using

```
if (serialPort.IsOpen == true)
{
serialPort.Write("Command1");
}
```

But my device does not respondes to it.

**To check,** I tried sending same command using hyperterminal to my
device and my device recognizes it and works perfectly.

Can anybody guide me whats the accurate way to write or what 
needs to be make sure for writing to serial port in c#. Is this encoding issue...
(Serial Read using this same app is working pretty fine !!)
Thank you for your time.

Moreover, there is no exception or error and in debug mode
this line executes.

Comment: Have you tried `serialPort.Write(@"Command1\n");`? Also, your conditional should just be `if (serialPort.IsOpen)`; no need to test it against `true`; it's already boolean.

Comment: Just looking at some of my ancient serial stuff and I see as Andrew mentioned I am sending \r\n and using  serialPort.WriteLine

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't think you can use `"\n"` escape sequence in verbatim string literals.

Comment: How do you send the command using hyperterminal? Do you need to press `Enter`?

Comment: @AlvinWong Yes; that's why I typed `@"Command1\n"` The `@` means \ don't escape. Or you can instead double-escape them like this: `"Command1\\n"`

Comment: @AndrewBarber I thought usual devices would expect `"\n"` instead of `"\\n"`.

Comment: @AlvinWong Yes. `"\n"` Which in order to get in C#, you need to use `"\\n"` or `@"\n"`

Comment: @AndrewBarber I mean the serial device would response to an actual newline character (`0x10`) other than \n (`0x5c 0x6e`).

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I tried serialPort.Write(@"Command1\n"); but it still does not work. One thing I am constantly also receiving data from the device after every 2 sec. But I dont think it will effect write, as same works on hyperterminal. (also receive works on a diff thread. I have something like private void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) ). Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common problem and invariably caused by leaving the Handshake property set to None.  Serial port devices almost always pay attention to the handshake signals and ignore anything you send if the DTR signal isn't turned on.  Which indicates that you are powered up and the data it receives isn't noise.  Setting DtrEnable to true will be required, that's what HyperTerminal does as well.

And it won't send anything back when it thinks you are not ready to receive anything because the RTS signal isn't turned on.  Setting RtsEnable to true will be required, that's what HyperTerminal does as well.  Or just set the Handshake property correctly, Handshake.RequestToSend is the common requirement.

If you still have trouble then you can use SysInternals' PortMon to compare the serial port driver commands your program issues against the ones issued by HyperTerminal.

Comment: Awesome ! You are absolutely right about handshaking. Thanks it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hyperterminal likely appends a newline character to your input when you hit the Enter key to send information, which consists of a "line feed" and "carriage return".

Check the documentation for your hardware, but my guess is that the device you're attempting to send information to is looking for a carriage return, '\r', to signify the end of input. Like others in the comments are saying, append the appropriate character(s) to the end of your input.

Alternatively, you can use the SerialPort.WriteLine function to accomplish the same thing as appending a newline '\r\n' character to your input without explicitly modifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your input together with @Hans Passant solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (serialPort.IsOpen)
    serialPort.WriteLine("Command" + "\r\n");
```